# how to perform a search on work profile contacts

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am facing one problem and not getting solution on internet.
I am able to list all user profile contacts but its not showing contacts from work profile.

please refer to below links for detail about work profile
 https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949?hl=en
 https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7029561?hl=en

`

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION =
        {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME

        };

private static final String SELECTION =
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?" :
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?";

@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
        /*
         * Makes search string into pattern and
         * stores it in the selection array
         */
        mSelectionArgs[0] = "%" + mSearchString + "%";
        // Starts the query
        return new CursorLoader(
                getActivity(),
                Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION,
                SELECTION,
                mSelectionArgs,
                null
        );
    }
`
```

For example: i have a contact with name "todd" in normal profile on the other hand i have a "tom" in contact under my work profile. Now in native message app during compose it shows todd and tomm both. i want same to happen in my implementation.

How should i get work profile contacts?

Comment: No experience with Work Profiles, but one thing caught my eye from your first link. Under "_What will my organisation be able to control_" there is "_Restrict what can be shared across personal and work profiles_". I don't know how these restrictions work, but I can conceive one way would be for them ("work") to "white-list" apps that can access work-profile contacts, and your app may not be on that list (while the native message app might be). Also, can we assume (as per 2nd link) you've not turned the work profile off?

Comment: i have't turned work profile off, when work profile is off no app(even native) can access the content/apps/contacts belonging to work profile.

Answer (score 1):

refer to the code below that solved my problem

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION_ENTERPRISE = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA1,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL
    };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        private Cursor getEnterpriseContact(String searchString, String[] cols, ContactSearchType mContactSearchType, String digits, String sortOrder) {
            // Get the ContentResolver
            ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
            // Get the Cursor of all the contacts
            Uri phoneUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ENTERPRISE_CONTENT_FILTER_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.DIRECTORY_PARAM_KEY, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.Directory.ENTERPRISE_DEFAULT)).build();
            Uri phoneUriWithSearch = Uri.withAppendedPath(phoneUri, Uri.encode(searchString));
            Cursor pCursor = cr.query(phoneUriWithSearch, cols, null, null, sortOrder);
            Cursor workCur = null;
            if (mContactSearchType != ContactSearchType.CONTACT_WITH_PHONE_NO) {
                Uri emailUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ENTERPRISE_CONTENT_FILTER_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.DIRECTORY_PARAM_KEY, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.Directory.ENTERPRISE_DEFAULT)).build();
                Uri emailUriWithSearch = Uri.withAppendedPath(emailUri, Uri.encode(searchString));
                Cursor eCursor = cr.query(emailUriWithSearch, cols, null, null, sortOrder);
                workCur = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{pCursor, eCursor});
            } else {
                workCur=pCur;
            }
     return workCur;
    }
```